# Convert a textured 3D mesh to a 3D colored mesh

Tags: 3d, textures, meshlab

I'm trying to convert a textured mesh (.3DS that I'm reading with Meshlab). I want to convert it to a 3D colored mesh (a an RGB color per vertex). For this, I'm saving it into a .ply extension. However, when I Open it, I don't find the RGB colors associated to each vertex. Is it possible to do this conversion ?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, what you described is an integrated plug-in in [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/). Just try via cmd: Filters->Texture->Transfer:Texture to vertex color.